# Imported flash builder project unable to open swc

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I wanted to import an older FB project into the flash builder on my new pc, but I only have the filestructure. So I used 'import>existing projects into workspace'.
The files seem to be intact still, but the project now gives me an error regarding an swc in the bin folder: 'unable to open \'something'\bin\'something'.swc

I have no idea how to solve this, or what this even means. Can somebody lend me a hand here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be referring to an old library project that you forgot to include in your workspace (or open).  In Eclipse, when you specify a path as `/your-library-project/some/path`, it automatically resolves the real path to whatever you're trying to reference.

In this particular case, you were referring to the swc created by this library project and linking to it directly. To fix this issue, you'll need to find the library project and import it into your workspace.